# jQuery find element upper in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="author" data-id="1"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>    
    <div class="post"></div>  
    ...........................
    <div class="author" data-id="5"></div> // This is the target i need to get later
    <div class="post"></div>    
    <div class="post"></div>  

    <div class="author current" data-id="6"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>    
    <div class="post"></div>    
    <div class="post"></div>  
    .............................
    <div class="author" data-id="10"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>    
</div>
```

And scripts:

```
$('.author.current').click(function(){
     var $current_author = $(this);
     var $prev_author = ...//Here i need to get the author div which is upper in the DOM tree(the one with comment)
     $current_author.removeClass('current')
     $prev_author.addClass('current')
})
```

As i wrote in the code i need to get previous author by clicking on current author. Number of authors can be infinite.

Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks to answers the right way is here:

```
 var $prev_author = $current_author.prevAll('.author').first()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try,

```
var $prev_author = $(this).prevAll('.author').first();
```

or

```
var $prev_author = $(this).closest('.content').find('.author:first');
```